# BindingSource Filter by date

Tags: c#, sql, filter, filtering

I want to filter values from database based on date.

Date in a database contains values like this: 2008-12-28 18:00:00. And my class has a DateTime variable depending on which I want to filter. Ideally it would work like this:
`myBindingSource.Filter = "DATE(myDateField) = myDateTime.Date"` + adjusting myDateTime.Date format as needed.

But it throws an EvaluateException: "The expression contains undefined function call DATE()."

Although if I execute the SQL statement directly, I can use the DATE() function in filter.

P.S. I use MYSQL DB with the Connector/Net 5.2

How can I solve this problem?

Thank You all for suggestions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The getSqlDate function is not needed. You can use String.Format() to format dates:

```
String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd} 00:00:00", myDateTime)
```

OR

```
myDateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " 00:00:00"
```

You could filter the binding source like this:

```
myBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("myDateField >= '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' AND myDateField < '{1:yyyy-MM-dd}'", myDateTime, myDateTime.AddDays(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Tom H.

Yes, i wanted to eliminate the time portion of the datetime in the filter and your suggestion works perfectly.

I`ll leave the complete solution for others:

```
myBindingSource.Filter = "myDateField >= '" + getSqlDate(myDateTime) + "' AND myDateField < '" + getSqlDate(myDateTime.AddDays(1)) + "'";
```

where getSqlDate function is:

```
string getSqlDate(DateTime date) {
    string year = "" + date.Year;
    string month = (date.Month < 10) ? "0" + date.Month : "" + date.Month;
    string day = (date.Day < 10) ? "0" + date.Day : "" + date.Day;

    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " 00:00:00";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A correction to the answer:
Accoring to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)
,to get the correct date
the **mm** in

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

would have to be capitalized
like so;

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

to get a correctly formatted date.

Answer (score 0):

Is myDateField the name of the field in the dataset?  I think you want an expression like this:

```
myBindingSource.Filter = "myDateField = " & myDateTime.Date.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to eliminate the time portion of the datetime in the filter? I'm not too familiar with MySQL, but if you use any kind of function that returns the date portion of a datetime then you are likely to kill any chance of using an index on that column for the query (existing or future index).

Your best bet is to create a filter on the front end that checks for a range that is only for your given filter date. For example:

```
myBindingSource.Filter = "myDateField >= " & <code to create a string representing 12AM of your date> &
" myDateField < " & <code to create a string for 12AM of the next day>
```

Sorry for not having exact code, but I'm a SQL developer and my lack of VB/C# skills would require me to take a lot more time to come up with the functions then it would probably take you. :)

Answer (score 0):

For search between two date in DataGridView you can use this code :

```
BindingSource1.Filter = "F5 >= '" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "' And " + "F5 <= '" + maskedTextBox2.Text + "'";

BindingSource1 : my datagridview datasourc load in BindingSource1 .
F5             : name of your header column in datagridview . 
maskedTextBox1 : for get first date .
maskedTextBox2 : for get second date .
```

Answer (score 0):

For search between two date in DataGridView you can use this code :

```
BindingSource1.Filter = "F5 >= '" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "' And " + "F5 <= '" + maskedTextBox2.Text + "'";
```

BindingSource1 : my datagridview datasourc load in BindingSource1 .
F5             : name of your header column in datagridview . 
maskedTextBox1 : for get first date .
maskedTextBox2 : for get second date .

Be successfull "Arn_7"

Comment: Nope, you can't do that, could you please review your answer ? you should not use concatenation to construct sql queries, specially directly from a user input, and moreover, there is going to be a huge formatting problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add  signle quotes like this "'2021-09-26'".

```
myBindingSource.Filter = "myDateField = " + "'" + myDateTime.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'"
```