# SQL query in VB - Missing operand

Tags: vb.net

Just learning a bit of VB and want to search a very simple SQL query as follows:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    firstOrd = txtFirstOrd.Text
    Me.OrdersBindingSource.Filter = "select * from orders WHERE firstDate =" & firstOrd
End Sub
```

Ive just got this executing on a simple button and keep getting this:

```
Syntax error: Missing operand after 'orders' operator.
```

Im pretty sure its a **quote problem** but cant work it out! Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to **use the filter of a bindingSource**. This [filter property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may include a **condition** to check on each row of the given bindingSource

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    firstOrd = txtFirstOrd.Text
    Me.OrdersBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("firstDate = '{0}'", firstOrd)
End Sub
```

I assume `firstOrd` will contain a *dateTime value*, so may consider having a look at **[BindingSource.Filter by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400283/bindingsource-filter-by-date)**.

Comment: Hi Pilgerstorfer, yes 'firstOrd' is a dataTime value within the database. could you explain the '{0}' to me? Thanks for you help!

Comment: instead of concatenating every string I prefer using **String.Format**. This will replace `{0}` with the first value after , (here: `firstOrder`)

Comment: Tried that aswell Pilgerstorfer. I cant get my method to find the '.Filter By date' function of filtering. When i run your code above i get the following: Cannot perform '=' operation on System.DateTime and System.String.    Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you check the link to [BindingSource.Filter by Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400283/bindingsource-filter-by-date)

Comment: Hi Pilgerstorfer, Thanks for the help I've sorted it now. Used a DataTimePicker in the end and just used one line of code. Turns out that the Binding Source dosent like the WHERE clause etc and just needed the very end of the query. Many thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you’re using and SQL interpreter which considers `orders` a keyword in SQL. To make it clear that it’s a table name, quote it.

```
"select * from [orders] WHERE firstDate =" & firstOrd
```

However, it’s generally recommended (but not always practical) just to avoid table names which are keywords.

Comment: Hi Konrad, tried that aswell earlier and got this  Syntax error: Missing operand after '[orders]' operator.