# Simple BIndingSource Filter by DateTime Property

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to filter a `BindingSource` given a property of type `DateTime`? Something simple such as `BindingSource.Filter = 'start_time Desc'`.

However, this does nothing. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: See the following, see if this addresses what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400283/bindingsource-filter-by-date

Answer (score 0):

An excerpt from the **Remarks** section of the `BindingSource.Filter` property [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Typically used in complex data-binding scenarios, the Filter property allows you to view a subset of the DataSource. **Only underlying lists that implement the IBindingListView interface support filtering.**
>
> When Filter is not null, the BindingSource **passes this property to the underlying list**. If you set this property during object initialization, the call will be deferred until after initialization is complete.
>
> To form a filter value, **specify the name of a column followed by an operator and a value to filter on**. The accepted **filter syntax depends on the underlying data source**. If the underlying data source is a DataSet, DataTable, or DataView, you can specify Boolean expressions using the syntax documented for the DataColumn.Expression property.

I've highlighted in bold the important parts. As you may see, the `BindingSource` does not provide the filtering capability itself. Whether it's supported and the syntax depends on the underlying data soure, i.e. the one that you set to `BindinigSource.DataSource` property.

The next applies **only** if you use a `DataTable` (`DataView`) as underlying source. Then as mentioned above you can use the syntax described here [DataColumn.Expression Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

Some things to note:

- Equality operator is `=` (not `==` like in C#)
- Date values must be enclosed in `#`
- All literal expressions must be expressed in the **invariant culture** locale.

For instance, filtering by a specific `start_time` value in your example could be something like this

```
DateTime startTime = ...;
BindingSource.Filter = "start_time = #" + startTime.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "#";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The `startTime` variable is already bound to the `DataGridView`. I made a mistake in the original question. I'm trying to `Sort` the rows after one value has been changed.